# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, xcode8

I have a problem with ionic.

Android version works perfect but ios stuck at loading with this error:

```
objc[11174]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x118e9c998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x118cc1d38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2016-10-28 17:20:25.395 stormApp[11174:718396] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.2.1 is starting.
2016-10-28 17:20:25.396 stormApp[11174:718396] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2016-10-28 17:20:25.440 stormApp[11174:718396] Using UIWebView
2016-10-28 17:20:25.441 stormApp[11174:718396] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.048995ms
2016-10-28 17:20:25.442 stormApp[11174:718396] Unlimited access to network resources
2016-10-28 17:20:25.442 stormApp[11174:718396] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.108050ms
2016-10-28 17:20:25.442 stormApp[11174:718396] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.075996ms
2016-10-28 17:20:25.450 stormApp[11174:718396] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 7.422984ms
2016-10-28 17:20:25.453058 stormApp[11174:718396] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/milospetrovic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B40570E-E119-4153-8C85-FE675F5F894A/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2016-10-28 17:20:25.453289 stormApp[11174:718396] [MC] Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID: com.stormApp, source account management: 1
2016-10-28 17:20:25.454858 stormApp[11174:718396] [MC] Result: NO
2016-10-28 17:20:25.454 stormApp[11174:718396] [CDVTimer][socialsharing] 4.113972ms
2016-10-28 17:20:25.455 stormApp[11174:718396] [CDVTimer][backgroundfetch] 0.060022ms
2016-10-28 17:20:25.456 stormApp[11174:718396] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.750959ms
2016-10-28 17:20:25.456 stormApp[11174:718396] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 15.021026ms
2016-10-28 17:20:26.206 stormApp[11174:718396] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2016-10-28 17:20:26.523 stormApp[11174:718396] Finished load of: file:///Users/milospetrovic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B40570E-E119-4153-8C85-FE675F5F894A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8EDDEAA1-2432-4561-AA38-D60052F554D4/stormApp.app/www/index.html#/event/home
2016-10-28 17:20:26.530 stormApp[11174:718396] -[SQLitePlugin pluginInitialize] [Line 33] Initializing SQLitePlugin
2016-10-28 17:20:26.531 stormApp[11174:718396] -[SQLitePlugin pluginInitialize] [Line 44] Detected docs path: /Users/milospetrovic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B40570E-E119-4153-8C85-FE675F5F894A/data/Containers/Data/Application/1B3FD16D-EAA1-4496-9A18-AFE53F8E578D/Documents
2016-10-28 17:20:26.531 stormApp[11174:718396] -[SQLitePlugin pluginInitialize] [Line 48] Detected Library path: /Users/milospetrovic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B40570E-E119-4153-8C85-FE675F5F894A/data/Containers/Data/Application/1B3FD16D-EAA1-4496-9A18-AFE53F8E578D/Library
2016-10-28 17:20:26.539 stormApp[11174:718396] -[SQLitePlugin pluginInitialize] [Line 55] no cloud sync at path: /Users/milospetrovic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B40570E-E119-4153-8C85-FE675F5F894A/data/Containers/Data/Application/1B3FD16D-EAA1-4496-9A18-AFE53F8E578D/Library/LocalDatabase
2016-10-28 17:20:26.539 stormApp[11174:718680] -[SQLitePlugin openNow:] [Line 137] open full db path: /Users/milospetrovic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B40570E-E119-4153-8C85-FE675F5F894A/data/Containers/Data/Application/1B3FD16D-EAA1-4496-9A18-AFE53F8E578D/Library/LocalDatabase/demo.db
2016-10-28 17:20:26.540 stormApp[11174:718680] -[SQLitePlugin openNow:] [Line 163] Good news: SQLite is thread safe!
2016-10-28 17:20:27.201332 stormApp[11174:718396] 0x6100001578c0 Copy matching assets reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x6100001578c0> { count = 2, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "Assets" => <data: 0x6100002611c0>: { length = 1261 bytes, contents = 0x62706c6973743030d4010203040506666758247665727369... }
    "Result" => <int64: 0x610000220a60>: 0
}
2016-10-28 17:20:27.202929 stormApp[11174:718396] 0x608000158100 Copy assets attributes reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x608000158100> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "Result" => <int64: 0x6080002268a0>: 1
}
2016-10-28 17:20:27.203083 stormApp[11174:718396] [MobileAssetError:1] Unable to copy asset attributes
2016-10-28 17:20:27.203257 stormApp[11174:718396] Could not get attribute 'LocalURL': Error Domain=MobileAssetError Code=1 "Unable to copy asset attributes" UserInfo={NSDescription=Unable to copy asset attributes}
2016-10-28 17:20:27.206 stormApp[11174:718396] THREAD WARNING: ['TTS'] took '13.970947' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2016-10-28 17:20:27.207 stormApp[11174:718804] -[NSNull precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bd4ffb0
2016-10-28 17:20:27.208 stormApp[11174:718804] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bd4ffb0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba9234b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b4ca21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bb01f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba17c15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba17798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   libAXSpeechManager.dylib            0x00000001269b9816 -[AXSpeechAction preprocessAction] + 63
    6   libAXSpeechManager.dylib            0x00000001269bb81e -[AXSpeechManager _startNextSpeechJob] + 114
    7   libAXSpeechManager.dylib            0x00000001269bc4b5 -[AXSpeechManager _dispatchSpeechAction:] + 1585
    8   Foundation                          0x000000010affa6be __NSThreadPerformPerform + 326
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba37311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba1c59c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba1ba86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba1b494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    13  Foundation                          0x000000010afacff0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 274
    14  libAXSpeechManager.dylib            0x00000001269bf03d -[AXSpeechThread main] + 221
    15  Foundation                          0x000000010afbcee4 __NSThread__start__ + 1243
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010f021abb _pthread_body + 180
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010f021a07 _pthread_body + 0
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010f021231 thread_start + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

cordova plugin list   :

- com.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation 2.1.3 "BackgroundGeolocation"
- cordova-plugin-background-fetch 4.0.0 "CDVBackgroundFetch"
- cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.1.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
- cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.0 "Notification"
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.5.0 "InAppBrowser"
- cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.0 "StatusBar"
- cordova-plugin-tts 0.2.3 "TTS"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"
- cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.3 "SocialSharing"
- cordova-sqlite-storage 1.4.8 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
- ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
- onesignal-cordova-plugin 1.13.2 "OneSignal Push Notifications"

Can someone help me to solve this ? 
Thanks

Comment: did you solve it?